# Cypress - how to assert multiple errors at the same time

Tags: validation, automated-tests, cypress

I have a form, it has -say- 5 inputs which require to be filled up. I'd like to test that the validation kicks in correctly.
Thus I should be able find 5 errors messages upon trying to send the empty form.

I'd love to have something like:

```js
cy.get('form')
  .should('contain 5 times', 'You should fill this up, mate')
```

Is it possible or I have to waste endless virtual trees on useless repeated lines?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t work in this way. If you want it clean wrap it on external helper and use for your purpose.
The shortest way, would:

```
     cy.get('.error-text').each((item) => {
          expect(item).to.contain('You should fill this up, mate')
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```js
cy.get('form')
  .should('contain', 'You should fill this up, mate')
cy.get('.invalid-input-error-msg')
  .should('have.length', 5)
```

it's not perfect, but it's passable

Answer (score 0):

Below code suffice your requirement. If you something like below requirement.
Clicking on sign-up button without filling form you should see the error messages for each fields... All you have to correct is locator in the below code.

```
cy.get('#sign-up-button').click(); // Click on sign-up button for example without filling form
cy.get('form').within(() => { // Basically you are asserting inside form for each individual fields
     cy.get('#username').should('have.text', 'you should fill username input')
     cy.get('#password').should('have.text', 'you should fill password input')
     cy.get('#email').should('have.text', 'you should fill email input')
     cy.get('#address').should('have.text', 'you should fill address input')
     cy.get('#gender').should('have.text', 'you should fill gender input')
})
```